# How do I revive downed party members?

Tags: legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky

I'm playing the PSP version of **Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky**. One recent encounter with a monster KO'd one of my party members (apparently pine-cone monsters explode like bombs when reduced to 0 hp. Who knew?), and I'm at a loss as to how to get him back on his feet.

I know that you can use an item to recover from KO, and if you find and activate Orb Recharge station, that will also revive your lost party member, but if neither of those methods are available as options (for instance, if you're out of the revival item and far from a Recharge station), is there some other way to get my party back on its feet?

I've tried both Inns and Temples, and unlike other JRPGs, neither seems particularly inclined to help fix my companion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, Inns *are* the way to rest and restore your HP - in my case, it was simply a matter of still being in the prologue, and the option not yet being available. When I went back later, "Rest" was available as a conversation topic.

Dead on your feet? Sleep at an Inn!

Answer (score 4):

For future players also struggling with the no-inns-in-prologue...the sewers are still accessible (south of the church) and the orbment charging station is close to the entrance!